# How to set the captcha at the bottom of comments textarea

Tags: plugins

Hii I am new to word press. I have downloaded BotDetect captcha. It works finely. But currently it appears just above the comments text area. How can it be set at the bottom of comments text area.Can you help me??please

Comment: Anyone can you please share is there any way to place the captcha below the comments textarea

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/botdetect-wp-captcha

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it didn't answer my question. I have already downloaded the captcha plugin. But the captcha is appearing just above the comments text area. I need it just below the text area. So what should I do??

Comment: I am using zeesynergie theme. Please help me.

Comment: When I googled, I got the result that I have to place the code do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); just above the comments text area.Then captcha will appear below the comments text area. But I couldn't find such a code in comments.php in zeesynergie theme.

Comment: That means that whatever Theme you're using has comment form markup that's about three years out-of-date.